# Instantiate controller in joomla 3.1.1

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to instantiate a controller and execute some methods but no result :(

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
$controller = JController::getInstance('com_shop');
$controller->my_method($arg1, $arg2);
```

Any idea?

Comment: try this latest sample JOOMLA 3.0 extension as a reference.  http://lendr.websparkinc.com/

Answer (score 1):

This won't work try: `JControllerLegacy::getInstance('CONTROLLERNAME')` assuming that the controller you are calling follows the naming convention

`<COMPONENTNAME><Controller><CONTROLLERNAME>` for example `WeblinksControllerWeblink`

Answer (score 0):

following is controller instantiation code taken form [lender](http://lendr.websparkinc.com/). And you don't need to use jimport in Joomla 3 extensions. Joomla auto load all classes starting with `J` prefix.

```
<?php // No direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

//sessions
jimport( 'joomla.session.session' );

//load tables
JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT.'/tables');

//load classes
JLoader::registerPrefix('Lendr', JPATH_COMPONENT);

//Load plugins
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('lendr');

//application
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

// Require specific controller if requested
if($controller = $app->input->get('controller','default')) {
  require_once (JPATH_COMPONENT.'/controllers/'.$controller.'.php');
}

// Create the controller
$classname  = 'LendrController'.$controller;
$controller = new $classname();

// Perform the Request task
$controller->execute();
```